# If $D[x]$ is unique factorization domain (UFD) then $D$ is an UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $D$ be an integral domain and suppose the polynomial  $D[x]$ is an unique factorization domain (UFD). Does $D$ have to be an unique factorization domain? 
In other words, does the equivalence
$$D\text{ is an }UFD\Longleftrightarrow D[x]\text{ is an }UFD$$
holds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every element $x \in D$ has a factorization in $D[X]$. Now use $\deg(pq) = \deg(p) + \deg(q)$ for polynomials in an integral domain to conclude.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a non-UFD $D$ such that $D[X]$ is a UFD once we drop the restriction that $D$ should be an integral domain?

Comment: If $D[X]$ is a domain, $D$ is also a domain.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks!